# Essential Networking Commands

Tags: macos, terminal, network, wifi, command-line

I'm used to working with *Linux* so I like being able to do as much as possible from the comfort of my **Terminal.app** *bash shell.*

So.. What are the *essential networking commands* & utilities native to *Mac OS X?*

If that's potentially too broad, the main goal is just to be able to ***join/connect*** to a *WLAN Access Point* and the *Internet.*

> What (I think) I know so far is this:
>
> 1. There is no **`ip`**, **`iw`** or **`iwconfig`**. There is an **`ifconfig`**.
> 2. There is no **`ss`** utility. There is a ***BSD**-style*  **`netstat`** utility; but it's considerably different to ***GNU**-proper*.
> 3. There is a poorly documented ***IEEE 802.11*** utility; named **`airport`**.
>    I have it symbolically-linked (**`link -s`**) to my default **`$PATH`**. (i.e:**`/bin/airport`**)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27743/discussion-on-question-by-tjt263-essential-networking-commands).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `networksetup` and `airport` are your best bets.

run `ifconfig` to find network interfaces,
then `airport scan` to find available networks,
and then `networksetup -setairportnetwork INTERFACE SSID PASSWORD`
where INTERFACE, SSID, and PASSWORD are replaced by the proper items.
It's not the most elegant method, but it works.